# How to make a button not show up but still be used by javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using a button that has to be invible and should be used by a javascript function.

```
<asp:Button ID ="btnDummy1" runat="server" Visible ="true" OnClick="btnSubmit1_Click" width="0px" height="0px"/
```

I cannot keep visible = false as it the javascript will not use invible content in the poage. I havetried to give width=0 and height=0, still it showws up in Chrome. What do you guys think i should do?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's the point in using an invisible button? If your code is in a function itself, you can call that function without needing that button.

Comment: In my case, so I can add additional drop down lists depending on the user's need for more drop down lists.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A pretty clean approach in ASP.Net it give it a "hidden" class:

```
<asp:Button ID ="btnDummy1" runat="server" CssClass="hidden" />
```

Then in your stylesheet:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Comment: This will make the button invisible, until CSS is disabled.

Comment: @mike - that's precisely what the question is asking for...he's not trying to pass data, he's trying to invoke some ASP.Net functionality (though there are other cleaner ways to do that if indeed the case -  that's a different topic though, and answered elsewhere).

Answer (score 6):

If you set it to `Visible="False"` then the code will not be executed.

Instead I think you should wrap it in a `<div>` and set `display:none` via css:

```
<div style="display: none;">
   <asp:Button ID ="btnDummy1" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit1_Click" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

adding style="display:none" would hide the button till you make it visible again

```
<asp:Button ID ="btnDummy1" runat="server"  OnClick="btnSubmit1_Click" style="display:none"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
style="display:none"
```

for the button instead of Visible = "true".

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use a hidden form field in this case? This is generally the preferred method of passing information along.

See http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlhidden.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnMyOrders" runat="server" Text="my orders" CssClass="dropdown-item" OnClick="btnMyOrders_Click" Visible="False" />
```

Example then in Form(){

btn.Visible = true; to show it again
}

Comment: Please don‘t add code without explanation, what this code-snipped do.

Comment: i add button and i add
Visible="False" to disable the button
then when i need the button to show 
NAmeBUTTON.Visible = True ;

Answer (score -1):

I think the first question you should ask yourself is : why would I put in my HTML doc a button that should not be visible ?

An HTML document should be used ONLY TO DESCRIBE A CONTENT'S SEMANTICS. So an HTML doc should ONLY contain the content you want to publish and extra data to explain the content's SEMANTIC !! NOTHING about the way it is displayed, NOTHING about the way it behaves !!

All displaying and behaviors questions should be managed with CSS and Javascript, NEVER within HTML itself.

Any element needed for Javascript only purpose should be added in the doc by Javascript itself !

You should never find, in an HTML doc, such things as prev/next buttons for a javascript picture gallery for example. The HTML doc should only contain the pictures list, than your JS script will change the way this list is shown, making it a eye candy gallery and add buttons for navigation.

So in your example, your saying you want to add in your HTML doc an invisible button with some Javascript actions on it.... that's probably an example of some content that should never be in the HTML doc.

Comment: It made me think. Thanks Nicolas.